# Disabling/Enabling IBOutlet determines if I get touches or not?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to overlay a transparent image over my app, with the purpose of explaining the controls of that view. When the UIImageView is first touched it should simply disappear. My MainViewController has the touchesBegan/Ended methods implemented and they work fine until I connect the UIImageView to an IBOutlet in MainViewController. Simply stop responding to events. What am I doing wrong?

```
-MainView
--ScrollView
--OtherView
--UIImageView (this is the overlay)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UIImageViews do not have user interaction turned on by default. If you want it on, either set the property via IB, User Interaction Enabled or via code...

```
[myImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
```

Comment: It's already enabled. As you can see I did receive the events until I connected it to the IBOutlet.

Comment: Hmm, the normal approach to this is to have a transparent UIButton with type UIButtonTypeCustom, no title or anything and hook up the touch up inside event. It's a more robust and quicker way of achieving this without having you intercept touch events.

Comment: I ended up creating a custom UIImageView with a delegate. A button would have been easier :)